# Axis and tick labels are bold when they shouldn't be - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been making lots of plots with Matplotlib for a report and I've been formatting them all the same; increasing font sizes and things.  However, on some of them using exactly the same commands seems to be giving different results - the tick labels are being rendered in a bold font when I haven't told them to be.

As far as I can tell, all the relevant bits of my program (plotting bits) are the same and look like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 10
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 10

for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(30)

ax.set_ylabel('Normalised magnetisation (a.u.)', fontsize = 30, labelpad=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (K)', fontsize = 30, labelpad=15)

ax.set_ylim(-1.2, 1.2)
ax.set_xlim(0, 65)

plt.locator_params(axis = 'y', nbins=4)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18, left=0.18)

plt.savefig('path/to/file', bbox_inches='tight')
```

All these commands are the same for multiple plots and just a few have the bold problem.  Is there anything obvious I'm missing?  Is there some way the way I'm manipulating my data affects the tick labels?

Many thanks.

Edit: It's only the tick labels that are problematic, not the axis labels.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you provide a comparison of the bold and non-bold text? (Say a print screen or something)

Comment: @Ffisegydd Edited the post, should be a link to an image there now.

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to the "x10^-4" in the top left corner. I suspect it is causing some change to the font properties when it is being included. Could you check your other plots to see if this problem only occurs when that scientific notation is used?

Comment: @Ffisegydd I have other plots without the 10e-4 that don't have this problem. That plot has the line `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y')` to give that, but adding that line to other plots doesn't make a difference to boldness.

Comment: Are you positive the `fontsize` for the ticks is identical for all the plots? It might seem `bold` when it is bigger.

Comment: @TheDude I've just gone through all the files and changed the font size to 30. Still get the different results though.

Comment: hysteresis curve?

Comment: @wander95 Yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 10
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 10
```

to

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 10
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Don't ask me why ;)